# How do I average columns block-wise?

Tags: matlab, matrix, average

Say, for example, I have the following matrix:

```
[1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4

1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4

1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4]
```

How could I programmatically average together, say, every four columns so that I would end up
with:

```
[2.5 2.5

2.5 2.5

2.5 2.5]
```

?

Thanks,

Tom

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be done without loops using [`reshape`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html):

```
A = [1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4
     1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4
     1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4]; %// data matrix
N = 4; %// number of columns to average
result = squeeze(mean(reshape(A,size(A,1), N, []), 2));
```

---

If you have the Image Processing Toolbox, you can also use [`blockproc`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/images/ref/blockproc.html):

```
result = blockproc(A, [size(A,1) N], @(x) mean(x.data, 2))
```

Comment: interesting reshape to 3d and re-squeeze approach ;)

Comment: @Thomas Thanks! I was considering deleting my answer because yours was first, but then you deleted it. Why did you?

Comment: I noticed I had the columns/rows swapped in the result and your answer was correct.

Answer (score 3):

One approach based on `sum` and `reshape` -

```
reshape(sum(reshape(A,size(A,1),N,[]),2)/N,size(A,1),[])
```

---

Some benchmarks for the solutions posted thus far are presented here.

Benchmarking Code -

```
m = 1000; %// No. of rows in input
n = 4000; %// No. of cols in input
A = rand(m,n); %// Input with random data
N = 4; %// number of columns to average;
num_runs = 200; %// No. of iterations

disp('----------------- With sum+reshape');
tic
for k1 = 1:num_runs
    out1 = reshape(sum(reshape(A,size(A,1),N,[]),2)/N,size(A,1),[]);
end
toc,clear out1

disp('----------------- With mean+reshape');
tic
for k1 = 1:num_runs
    out2 = squeeze(mean(reshape(A,size(A,1), N, []), 2));
end
toc,clear out2

disp('----------------- With blockproc');
tic
for k1 = 1:num_runs
    out3 = blockproc(A, [size(A,1) N], @(x) mean(x.data, 2));
end
toc,clear out3

disp('----------------- With filter');
tic
for k1 = 1:num_runs
    B = filter(ones(1,N)/N,1,A,[],2);
    out4 = B(:,N:N:end);
end
toc,clear out4 B
```

Results -

```
----------------- With sum+reshape
Elapsed time is 4.011844 seconds.
----------------- With mean+reshape
Elapsed time is 3.945733 seconds.
----------------- With blockproc
Elapsed time is 59.018457 seconds.
----------------- With filter
Elapsed time is 31.220875 seconds.
```

Comment: +1 Good idea to use `sum` instead of the slow `mean`. And nice benchmarking!

Comment: @LuisMendo Yeah seems like using the basic ones really give us the performance!+1 already for you too! Forgot to mention that `squeeze` squeezes out the performance too!

Comment: @Divakar Nice idea, however for me (Matlab2011b, Win7) the mean+reshape beats the others reliably. Another fast solution is `display([2.5 2.5; 2.5 2.5; 2.5 2.5])` :D

Comment: @LuisMendo So I ran these for a no. of iterations and seems like it's neck-to-neck now between mean+reshape and sum+reshape! Sorry for the confusion earlier :)

Comment: @Divakar All other things being equal (which is not exactly the case here), `mean` should be a little slower because it does a check before calling `sum`

Answer (score 2):

A simple approach would be abusing [**`filter`**](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/ref/filter.html):

```
A = [1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 ;
     1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 ;
     1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 ]

N = 4;

B = filter(ones(1,N)/N,1,A,[],2)
C = B(:,N:N:end)
```

gives:

```
C =

    2.5000    2.5000
    2.5000    2.5000
    2.5000    2.5000
```

which seems quite a bit faster than all that reshaping and squeezing action ;) Without proof though.

Comment: @Thomas, you're right. Was just a typo, should work now.

Comment: Works now. I think the whole question is well explored now ;)

Comment: Using `filter` or `conv` is an interesting approach, but it computes `N` times more results than necessary (you then have to downsample with `N:N:end`). +1, though